# How to use .cov() function on ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

So i have a folowing problem:

1. I have some data in pandas dataframe format, so I use `pd.Dataframe().to_numpy()` to convert it to an array
2. Then I try to do .cov() ( Calculating the covariance matrix ) on that array, but it gives me and error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cov'`

What I did is i used `.ravel()` function on my array to make it a normal numpy array, but again the same error appears.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `cov` isn't provided as an array method, it's at the top level, so `np.cov(arr, *args)`

Comment: so how do i solve the problem?